# Deployment error during building in vercel. SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0

Tags: postgresql, next.js, deployment, prisma, vercel

Hi I'm newbie of coding and tried making todo app.

but encountered an error during building in vercel..

It works fine in dev environment.

Using Next13,typscript,prisma,postgreSQL,railway,tailwind

error code

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.json (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6160:23)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Home (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:478:18)
Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.json (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6160:23)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Home (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:478:18)
info  - Generating static pages (3/3)
> Build error occurred
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
    /page: /
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:415:19
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
    at async /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:1400:21
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
    at async /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:1259:17
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
    at async Object.build [as default] (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:66:29)
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

page.tsx

```
import PostForm from "../components/PostForm";
import Tasks from "../components/Tasks";


async function getPosts() {
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/api/getPosts`);
  if (!res.ok) {
    console.log(res);
  }
  return res.json();
}

export default async function Home() {

  const data: {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    content: string;
    timestamp: string;
  }[] = await getPosts();

  return (
    <div>
      <PostForm />
      <div className="sm:flex  sm:justify-center sm:items-baseline sm:flex-wrap max-w-7xl mx-auto mt-7">
        {data.reverse().map((post) => (
          <Tasks
            title={post.title}
            content={post.content}
            id={post.id}
            timestamp={post.timestamp}
          />
        ))}{" "}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

package-json

```
{
  "name": "testapp-next13-tailwind-prisma-postgresql-typescript",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@next/font": "13.1.6",
    "@prisma/client": "^4.9.0",
    "@types/react": "18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.10",
    "next": "13.1.6",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.11.19",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "prisma": "^4.9.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  }
}
```

You can see repository here
https://github.com/satoshi02198/Task-maker

I'd appriciate any help.Thanks in advance.

change code in page.tsx to client component with using useEffect for fetching data instead of server side rendering.(you can see that umcoment code in  the repository in page.tsx but that code also can't deploy)
I also checked Enviroment variable setting in vercel BASE_URL set to https://task-maker-3.vercel.app (that vercel try to deploy to) and DATABASE_URL for PostgreSQL

I edited page.tsx to this syntaxError seems resolve but new error come

```
async function getPosts() {
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/api/getPosts`);
        if (!res.ok) {
            console.log(res.json());
        }
          return res.text();
        }

export default async function Home() {
    const data = await getPosts();

     const jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
     console.log(jsonData);

  return (
    <div>
      <PostForm />
  <div className="sm:flex  sm:justify-center sm:items-baseline sm:flex-wrap max-w-7xl mx-auto mt-7">
    {jsonData
      .reverse()
      .map(
        (post: {
          title: string;
          content: string;
          id: number;
          timestamp: string;
        }) => (
          <Tasks
            title={post.title}
            content={post.content}
            id={post.id}
            timestamp={post.timestamp}
          />
        )
      )}{" "}
  </div>
</div>
);
}
```

and Vercel new error

```
TypeError: The body has already been consumed.
at consumeBody (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6072:19)
at consumeBody.next (<anonymous>)
at Response.text (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6146:28)
at getPosts (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:457:16)
at process.processTicksAndRejections   ( 
 node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async Home (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:460:18)
Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: 
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: The body has already been consumed.
at consumeBody (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6072:19)
at consumeBody.next (<anonymous>)
at Response.text (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6146:28)
at getPosts (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:457:16)
at process.processTicksAndRejections 
(node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async Home (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:460:18)
info  - Generating static pages (3/3)
> Build error occurred
 Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
/page: /
at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:415:19
at process.processTicksAndRejections 
 (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async Span.traceAsyncFn 
 (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
at async /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:1400:21
at async Span.traceAsyncFn 
(/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
at async /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:1259:17
at async Span.traceAsyncFn 
(/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
at async Object.build [as default] 
(/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:66:29)
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because the data or error returned by fetch is not a valid JSON object.

So instead of:

```
res.json()
```

do:

```
res.text()
```

And then you can do JSON.parse after you do an error check.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edited code as I update above. syntax error is resolved but new error come. anyway, I get new knowledge thanks to you. I appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue, and fixed it following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76779776/15288641). Basically the API is not available during build time IF you did not push the API before.

So what would be a solution push the API before you push code that consumes the API. As mentioned by Youssouf Oumar it's quite a hack, as you will encounter similar problems again if you change something in the API or if you deploy to prod.